# Javascript Increase max array size

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create an array of size `2^32 = 4294967296`, because I am trying to get all the prime numbers till 2^32 by running the sieve algorithm. However any operation in that array I get the following error:

> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
>
> Abort trap: 6

What can I do in above situation?

Comment: use an object instead of sparse arrays.

Comment: That's 4 billion elements. Why do you need an array that size?

Comment: Anyway, try 4294967295 instead ((2^32) - 1).

Comment: I'd suggest that you explain the actual problem you're trying to solve so we can offer you other ways to solve it besides allocating a ginormous array.

Comment: Basically, I am trying to get all the prime numbers up to 2^32 by running sieve.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Arrays can't be that big, the maximum length is 2<sup>32</sup>-1. According to [ECMAScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array-exotic-objects) spec,

> Every Array object has a length property whose value is always a
>   nonnegative integer less than 2<sup>32</sup>.
>
> A String property name *P* is an *array index* if and only if
>   ToString(ToUint32(*P*)) is equal to *P* and ToUint32(*P*) is not equal
>   to 2<sup>32</sup>−1.

Comment: Think his tag is `node.js` and the story is different than.

Comment: @skobaljic Node.js is an ECMAScript implementation.

Comment: Guess you know better. As far as I know it is just built on Javascript's engine and you can extend it many ways, far different than Javascript in browser.

Answer (score 7):

An array of `2^32` elements is basically `4 GB * size of an element`, so there are high chances it will not fit into memory.

The error you are getting is exactly that: the allocator cannot allocate enough space. You might want to consider another solution than allocating a several gigabytes array. Having a little more detail about what you are trying to achieve could help putting you on the right track! :)

Comment: I am trying to get all the prime numbers till 2^32 and trying to run the sieve algorithm.

Comment: There's a high chance it will not fit into memory because of an artificial limitation...

Answer (score 4):

For `node.js` just install [big-array](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-array).

> A resizable array using non-sequential block memory allocation.
>   Growing or shrinking the array does not require reallocation of the
>   entire array. Useful when you need to track a few trillion data
>   points.

Answer (score 1):

For a sieve algorithm, you need just one bit for each number to test...

Look for a bitset implementation (https://github.com/tdegrunt/bitset for instance).
This one will grow dynamically as you set bits in it. You can set and get bits, and each bit will tell you if `n` is a prime.

However, I recommend you test with max 100, not 2^32... because it will be slow...

Actually, bitset breaks between 10M and 100M on my Mac. I guess they don't use a byte array.

In coffee-script because it's less verbose...

```
Bitset = require 'bitset'

sieve = (maxSize)=>

    mark = (bitset)->
        markMultiplesOf = (n)->
            bitset.set(n*each) for each in [2..(maxSize / n)]

        markMultiplesOf each for each in [2..(maxSize / 2)] when bitset.get(each) is false

    showPrimes = (bitset)->
        console.log each for each in [0..(bitset.length())] when bitset.get(each) is false

    timestamp = Date.now()

    bitset = new Bitset(maxSize)
    mark bitset, maxSize

    console.log "took #{Date.now() - timestamp} ms"
    showPrimes(bitset)

sieve(10000000) # takes < 4s
```